# Include en Sub Carpetas en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, rutas

Estoy trabajando un software con PHP, la carpeta del proyecto se llama `"sge"` , en donde tengo subcarpetas llamadas `"controlador"`, y dentro de esta, tengo un archivo de configuración de base de datos llamada `"csBDDCon.php"` en la raíz, y dentro de `"controlador"` tengo dos carpetas llamadas `"usuario"` y `"login"` , en los que necesito el `"include('csBDDCon.php');"` para poder llamar esa conexión de base de datos en cada uno de estos archivos, pero, a la hora de hacerlo, me marca error, estoy intentando de esta forma:

```
include ("../sge/csBDDCon.php");
```

Y también de esta otra forma:  `include("../controlador/csBDDCon.php");`  , esto, dentro de mi archivo en la ruta: `controlador/login/csLogin.php`

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Warning: include(../../csBDDCon.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\sge\controlador\login\csLogin.php on line 15

Comment: No funciona amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

como estás?

Si las subcarpetas en las que tienes los archivos en los que tienes que incluir el archivo de configuración, están dentro de "controlador" , solo debes saltar un directorio e incluirlo de ahí.

sge/controlador/login/csLogin.php

```
<?Php
include("../csBDDCon.php");" //En este punto estarias en /sge/controlador/
?>
```

Saludos!

Comment: EXCELENTE! , funcionó sin inconvenientes, ¡Gracias!